# block only one function from inherited class

Tags: c++, inheritance

i want to make a class that blocks only one function from the parent class.
for example:

```
class basememory{
    char *mem;
protected:
    basememory(int size){mem=new char[size];}
public:
    char read(int i){return mem[i];}
    void write(int i, char a){mem[i]=a;}
};

class rom: public basememory{
public:
    rom(int size, char *ch, int arr): basememory(size){
        for(int i=0;i<arr;i++){
            write(i, ch[i]);
        }
    } //burned to rom
};
class ram: public basememory{
public:
    ram(int size): basememory(size){}

};
```

i dont want write() function to be accessible from outside **only for the rom class**.
is there a way to do this without changing the basememory class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `protected` or `private` inheritance, and then publicize the functions you do want to expose:

```
class rom: protected basememory
{
public:
    rom(int size, char *ch, int arr): basememory(size){ ..... }

    using basememory::read;
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

Note that this means you cannot pass a `rom` to a function expecting `basememory` by reference/pointer -- because `basememory` has `write` being public, so if it were possible to convert a `rom` to a `basememory` reference it would circumvent `rom`'s access specifiers.